# Twitter bootstrap carousel misbehaves when minimized

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have twitter bootstrap 3 and the carousel slider in a page that I am designing, but when I go to other pages tabs and leave this on background or minimized, the carousel slider in that page is running wildly and making my laptop heat up very fast. 
Is normal this behavior of the carousel slider as a task on background?

code

```
<div id="carousel-slider" class="slide">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img class="hide-on-mobile" src="images/back2.png" alt="" />
    <div class="carousel-caption ">
    <div class="col-md-7 animated fadeInDownBig">
    <p>text</p>
         </div>
    </div>
</div> //x4 items

js:
$('.carousel-slider, #carousel-slider').carousel({
});
```

could be that I am using many transition css3 on links, some text, etc? 
thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you used?

Comment: So you realize you have nested carousels right? Why are you calling it on both `.carousel-slider` and `#carousel-slider`?

Comment: mmm maybe that is causing my trouble? just now I am seeing the documentation and seems not necessary to add that js code,it was just in case that I need more that one slider in the page,